# SQL | Min and Max dates from multiple rows by sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get the below result from my table.

When the sequence is the same I want to take Min of `start_dt` and Max of `end_dt`. But I also have `null` in the sequence, and I don't want those to be grouped.

I tried with `dense rank` but it didn't work. Maybe I should be using something like an intermediary table with a new sequence - but I don't know how to achieve that.

How can I achieve this result?

My table:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What is the role of `new sequence` in your table? Also, can you tag your question with the database engine you are on?

Comment: New sequence was the result I was thinking to achieve in order to group them after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all` to combine the grouped results with the individual results that have a `null` as `sequence`:

```
select   id, min(start_dt), max(end_dt), sequence
from     mytable
group by id, sequence
having   sequence is not null
union all
select   id, start_dt, end_dt, sequence
from     mytable
where    sequence is null;
```

If your database has a way to generate a unique number or has a unique identifier for each row (preferred!), then you can use that as extra expression in the `group_by` clause, in a `coalesce` expression.

For instance, in MySQL, you can do:

```
select   id, min(start_dt), max(end_dt), sequence
from     mytable
group by id, sequence, coalesce(sequence, UUID());
```

On SQL Server, you can do:

```
select   id, min(start_dt), max(end_dt), sequence
from     mytable
group by id, sequence, coalesce(sequence, NEWID());
```

Comment: Thanks, can you still respond to my other comment? (i.e. "can you tag your question with the database engine you are on")

Comment: the only problem that Im now investigating is that if the same ID has 2 sequences with null in 2 different time periods it would group them and it would not be proper. because I would have an overlap of dates

Comment: Can you create dbfiddle that illustrates the issue? I don't see how the query would group null values...

Answer (score 0):

I see that you grouped by the empty value as well in the expected result image attached. If this is what you need then you can simply use a 'group by' statement.

```
select Sequence, min(start_dt) as start_dt, max(end_dt) as end_dt from your_table
group by Sequence
```

However, if you don't want to group by the empty value you can either eliminate it with a 'HAVING' clause with the aforementioned 'group by' statement, or even by using a 'WHERE' clause in an intermediate table then using a 'group by' statement on the resulting table.

```
select Sequence, min(start_dt) as start_dt, max(end_dt) as end_dt from 
( select * from your_table where Sequence is not null) as s
group by Sequence
```